# Excel: how to normalize values in a column within a certain range

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I am looking to normalize all the values that appear within a column in an Excel file within the range of -1 to 1. The values in this column are currently within a range of -1.53 to 1.53. Is there a way to modify the formula for the column in order to fit the values within the desired range?

Answer (score 0):

If the values are in column **A**, then in **B1** enter:

```
=A1/1.53
```

and copy down

Comment: I actually figured out what I needed to do: =-1+((((AT:AT)-MIN(AT:AT)))*2/(MAX(AT:AT)-MIN(AT:AT))),    where AT is the column to normalize. Thank you for your input!